# Regarding page response

Tags: python

When I use requests library, I get different status code (error 503) but when I inspect page and lookout for status  it shows (error 404).
I tried this:

```
import requests

print(requests.get("https://www.amazon.de/dp/1015").status_code)
```

How can I get exact response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you are getting different responses is that your browser is sending headers. Headers are extra information about a request. Browsers always send specific headers, and one is the `User-Agent` header.

If amazon sees this header, it thinks that there is a browser asking for the page, so it is programmed to send a `404` response.

Without this header, it sends a `503` response because it knows you aren't using a browser. That's just what it's programmed to do.

To add headers, use:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0'}

req = requests.get("https://www.amazon.de/dp/1015", headers=headers)
print(req.status_code)
```

which prints `404`.

The `User-Agent` header tells amazon details about your browser and computer. To find your own `User-Agent` header, look at the headers in the `Network` part of your browser's inspector tab.